# How to test void methods using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I've seen a few questions out there regarding this but I can't seem to make sense of any of the answers for my particular problem.

I have a mock object, lets call "object1", which I send to some method for testing, lets call testMethod(). So I end up calling

```
testMethod(object1);
```

for testing. Now somewhere in this testMethod, there will be a part where it calls a method

```
object1.toggleDisplay();
```

which is a void method. If the method were like

```
object1.getDisplay()
```

where it actually returns something, I usually do

```
EasyMock.expect(object1.getDisplay()).andReturn(whatever);
```

However, this is a void method, and I would like to just test that this has been indeed been called for a certain amount of times. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If things haven't changed in the last few years, you use `expectLastCall` when setting up your expectations.

```
object1.toggleDisplay();
object.expectLastCall();
```

Comment: Wait so I have to put object.expectLastCall() inside my actual method? I have my Unit test classes and my actual program classes separated, and would prefer not to have unit test code inside my actual program.

Comment: No, you put the method call and `expectLastCall().times(NUM_TIMES)` inside your unit test where you would have previously have used `EasyMock.expect(object1.getDisplay()).andReturn(whatever)`

Comment: Is there any way I can do this to target specific methods? Like for example I have methods toggleOn() and toggleOff()

Comment: Yes: just add `expectLastCall()` after each method expectation. It applies to the definition of the last (most recent) call :-) If in doubt, try it out!

Answer (score 10):

```
object1.toggleDisplay();
EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(5);
```

or if you import statically the `EasyMock` methods:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;

[...]

object1.toggleDisplay();
expectLastCall().times(5);
```